# Solving the recurrence T(n) = T(n/2) + lg n?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, recurrence, master-theorem

I am having some issues on how to solve recurrence relations.

> T(n) = T(n/2) + log2(n), T(1) = 1, where n is a power of 2

This is a homework problem, so don't just give me the answer. I was just wondering how to start the problem.

In class we went over [the Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). But I don't think that would be the best way to solve this particular relation.

I don't really know how to start the problem... should I just be going

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + log_base2(n)
T(n/2) = [T(n/4)+log_base2(n/2)]
  T(n) = [T(n/4)+log_base2(n/2)] + log_base2(n)
```

And just keep working my way down to get something I can see makes a basic equation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question. Try math.stackexchange.com. 

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it is not about programming. Math questions may be asked on [math.SE] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7):

This recurrence solves to **Θ((log n)<sup>2</sup>)**. Here are two ways to see this.

## Some Substitutions

If you know that n is a perfect power of two (that is, n = 2<sup>k</sup>), you can rewrite the recurrence as

> T(2<sup>k</sup>) = T(2<sup>k-1</sup>) + k

Let's define a new recurrence S(k) = T(2<sup>k</sup>). Then we get that

> S(k) = S(k - 1) + k

If we expand out this recurrence, we get that

> S(k) = S(k - 1) + k
>
> = S(k - 2) + (k - 1) + k
>
> = S(k - 3) + (k - 2) + (k - 1) + k
>
> = S(k - 4) + (k - 3) + (k - 2) + (k - 1) + k
>
> ...
>
> = S(0) + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k
>
> = S(0) + Θ(k<sup>2</sup>)

Assuming S(0) = 1, then this recurrence solves to Θ(k<sup>2</sup>).

Since S(k) = T(2<sup>k</sup>) = T(n), we get that T(n) = Θ(k<sup>2</sup>) = Θ(log<sup>2</sup> n).

## Iterating the Recurrence

Another option here is to expand out a few terms of the recurrence and to see if any nice patterns emerge. Here’s what we get:

> T(n) = T(n / 2) + lg n
>
> = T(n / 4) + lg (n / 2) + lg n
>
> = T(n / 8) + lg (n / 4) + lg (n / 2) + lg n
>
> ...

Eventually, after lg n layers, this recurrence bottoms out and we’re left with this expression:

> lg n + lg (n / 2) + lg (n / 4) + ... + lg (n / 2<sup>lg n)</sup>

Using properties of logarithms, we can rewrite this as

> lg n + (lg n - 1) + (lg n - 2) + (lg n - 3) + ... + (lg n - lg n)

Or, written in reverse, this is the sum

> 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + lg n

That sum is Gauss’s sum up to lg n, which evaluates to (lg n)(lg n + 1) / 2 = Θ((log n)2).

Hope this helps!

Comment: hello sir , i am unable to move forward using your approach here https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E3iB.png

Comment: Instead of grouping all the log terms together at the end, split them apart. Use the fact that lg (n / 2^k) = lg n - k.

Comment: yes sir , i understand your approach .which you have done in your above qstn ..i was just curious to solve another way which i have given you the image :) thanks for reply

Comment: Oh, okay. The numerator of your fraction is n^{lg n}. The denominator is 2^{(lg n)(lg n + 1)/2}. What happens if you then apply the power and quotient rules for logarithms?

Answer (score 1):

If n is a power of 2 then you can just expand out the recurrence and solve exactly, using that lg(a/b) = lg(a) - lg(b).

```
T(n) = lg(n) + lg(n/2) + lg(n/4) + ... + lg(1) + 1
     = (lg(n) - 0) + (lg(n) - 1) .... + (lg(n) - lg(n)) + 1
     = lg(n)*lg(n) - lg(n)*(lg(n)+1)/2 + 1
     = lg(n)*lg(n)/2 - lg(n)/2 + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). Your `a=1` and `b=2` and `f(n) = log(n)`. Then `c = log2(1) = 0`. Because of your `c` and `f(n)` you fall into the second case (where `k=1`).

So the solution is **Θ(log<sup>2</sup> n)**

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the Akra-Bazzi theorem. See the third example in http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/DatAlg2008/NewMasterTheorem.pdf.